# xterm: how to disable mainMenu, vtMenu and fontMenu?

Tags: linux, xterm

Currently in my xterm, `Ctrl-<left_mouse_click>` shows the main menu (options for full screen etc). `Ctrl-<right_mouse_click>` shows the VT fonts menu.

I'd like to disable both of these menus, ultimately so that Vim can see both `Ctrl-<left_mouse_click>` and `Ctrl-<right_mouse_click>`

How can I do this?

Any points much appreciated.

Comment: You could go old school and add an xterm section to your .Xdefaults file that maps those keys to ignore(), not sure that'd pass them to vim or not and I'm not sure Wayland honors that file if you happen to be using that instead of X.  Look at the man page for xterm Custom Key Bindings section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the manual page, e.g., in [*Default Key Bindings*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings), which shows the `translations` resource with the assignments that you would have to override.  The [**`omitTranslation`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:omitTranslation) resource gives you a simple way to do this:

```
*omitTranslation: popup-menu
```

Wayland is irrelevant.

Comment: Superb, thank you. I literally have no idea how I missed the "Default Key Bindings" section in the man page. But also, the omitTranslation section is perfect.

Comment: what exactly did you do ?